# Flutter web a specific image is not showing only in production

Tags: flutter, web, production

[image]
Left(dev) Right(Prod) 
I have got an error which is an image is not showing in only production. 
If I run flutter web project in dev, the image shows properly.
I am using firebase hosting, I have double checked in build folder, the image locates perfectly fine. 
There is no error message such as "unable to load "image_1.png" stuffs. 
To add more, I try to use the image as background image. Beside this image, other images works fine. 
Is there anyone who faced this issue in flutter web? An image is not showing only in production.

- Using Image.asset() from local asset

I am expecting that how to show an image properly in flutter web production

Comment: What command did you use to get the web output?  You used canvaskit output or not?

Comment: were u able to find a solution? I have been having the same issue. Actually, my app was working fine with the images, and maybe after the flutter upgrade the images stopped showing up when I deploy the app.

Answer (score 0):

I did also encounter this when using a link image.network doest work at all in production so for me, I did is try out a package name [image_network](https://pub.dev/packages/image_network)
as per error i had is about on CORS as package solve this problem.

But you can try others answers

Comment: Thanks for sharing your case, but I'm using Image.asset() to show the image

Comment: hmmmm... I think this is the problem on the index which specify the path from own asset

Answer (score 0):

If you check on developer console (CTRL + Shift + I) on your browser, you will see that on production, the assets are put into another assets folder like below:
assets/assets/images/your_image.jpg, as opposed to assets/images/your_image.jpg.

In my case, I moved the assets folder to the root of the project, so I ended up having the following in the pubspec.yaml:

> flutter:
> uses-material-design: true
> assets:
> - fonts/
> - images/

And on referencing from code:

> Image.asset(
> "images/final_icon_bg.png",
> height: 80,
> width: 80,
> ),

So, if you put your assets in another folder, the referencing will work for mobile app but for the web app, they will be in another extra folder and end up not being loaded on the browser.
alternatively, dump your files in a folder under the root folder called assets. So your raw files are in assets and not in another folder. Then change your code references accordingly.